# How to put "done from both opposite sides" in one word?

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose I'm developing a method of covering a symmetric object with a coating. Commonly you'd have to put the coating on the front of the object, rotate it, and do the back. My method processes both sides at the same time. I need a single word to describe it:

*The novel method of _____ coating provides a 120% efficiency increase.*

I was thinking about [*bilateral*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bilateral), the definition states that it means something "located on opposite sides of an axis" - will it be clear enough? The word needs to not hint not only at the fact of doing something at opposing locations, but also with mirrored *alignments*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Double-sided** works for me. Or perhaps **dual** coating.

"Bilateral" is too strongly associated with politics and trade for its literal meaning to be used.